# How to handle automatically generated web element (id)

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests, qwebelement

I can't find element, because every time I refresh page, the element id is changed automatically

[image]

after refresh "input-19" is changed to any other, such as "input-2566"

how to handle these changes in selenium? to find elements..

**P.S. there is about ~20 checkbox'es with a same element. Differs only number after input.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below xpath, with method `contains`

```
//label[contains(@for,'input') and contains(@class,'v-label theme--light')]
```

**update :**

You were missing `(`

```
private static By checkboxSpecialist = By.xpath("(//label[contains(@for,'input') and contains(@class,'v-label theme--light')])[5]");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is about ~ 20 checkboxes with a same element. Differs only number after input. Added P.S. in summary.

Comment: Please use index `(//label[contains(@for,'input') and contains(@class,'v-label theme--light')])[1]`.. feel free to put `[2]` or `[3]`

Comment: `private static By checkboxSpecialist = By.xpath("//label[contains(@for,'input') and contains(@class,'v-label theme--light')])[5]");`  --- a syntax error is displayed

Comment: See above updated code. you were missing (

Answer (score 0):

u can try something like that:

```
const button = await driver.wait(
      until.elementLocated(By.xpath('YOUR XPATH ELEMENT')), 15000).then(button => {
      return driver.wait(
        until.elementIsVisible(button),
        15000)}
        })
      button3.sendKeys('your text ').then(async function() {
      console.log(button.sendKeys,'input - done');
      return true
    })
```

use xpath, not element id